# Möbius Transformation that moves zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Find a Möbius Transformation on complex plane, that moves $|z|<1$ to $|w|>2$ and point (0, 0) to (4, 0).

If we don't concern second condition, we can use $w(z) = \frac{2}{z}$. But later we can't apply the transition.

So I decided to transform cirle to a half-plane, then mirror it, and then convert it back to the cirle but with another radius. But this approach is very hard, and I'm stuck finding correct constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w(z) = 2/z$ maps the unit disk $\Bbb D$ to $|w| > 2$ with $w(1/2) = 4$. So we need to pre-compose this with a Möbius transformation $T$ which maps the unit disk onto itself and $T(0) = 1/2$.

The conformal automorphisms of the unit disk  are well-known, that are exactly the Möbius transformations of the form
$$
 T(z) = e^{i \lambda} \frac{z-a}{1-\overline a z }
$$
with $a \in \Bbb D$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$.

Choosing (for example) $\lambda = 0$ and $a = -1/2$ gives $T(0) = 1/2$, so that the desired mapping is
$$
 z \mapsto w(T(z)) = 2 \frac{1+z/2}{z+1/2} \, .
$$